# JavaScript document.write not appearing in page source

Tags: javascript, html

I have used `document.write('Test')` in my HTML page.

Everything is working as intended but I am just curious to know why this output 'Test' which appears in the browser does not appear in "View Page Source".

So the output of this `document.write()` is stored only in the browser memory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

When you ask to see the source code, the browser shows you the source code. It doesn't show you a serialisation of the current state of the DOM (which is what the DOM Inspector is for).

Answer (score 1):

View Source shows you the *source code* of the site. The exact thing that your browser initially received from the server. Anything happening from then on is modifying the *DOM* of the loaded document, it's not transforming into source code.